# how to get the separate contact name array list and contact number array list from the device

Tags: java, android

```
   ArrayList<String> contacts_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            PhoneNumber = c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contacts_list.add("ContactName:"+contactName + "\n" +"ContactNumber:"+PhoneNumber );

        }

        c.close();
```

In above code,getting the name and phone number but not separating the arraylist of contact number and names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Contact List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897286/android-contact-list)

Comment: please briefly write the code

Comment: also contact name and number passed to post method to service

Comment: am adding the contacts_list.add(contactName ); contacts_list.add(PhoneNumber); but returning result should be name and phone number

Comment: make a custom pojo class instead, and by making arraylist of it you can achieve what you want

Comment: use should go with the mahesh b's answer..it will work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class like this

```
public class NameContact {

private String name;
private String contact;

public NameContact(String name, String contact) {
    this.name = name;
    this.contact = contact;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}
}
```

then make an arraylist of it and add items in it..

```
ArrayList<NameContact> abc = new ArrayList<NameContact>();
abc.add(new NameContact("your_name","your_contact"));
```

Then After to put in RequestParams use this

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
JSONArray arrayName = new JSONArray();
JSONArray arrayContact = new JSONArray();

for(i = 0;i < contacts.size();i++ ) {
    arrayName.put(contacts.get(i).getName());
    arrayContact.put(contacts.get(i).getContact());    
}
params.put("ContactNameArray",arrayName);
params.put("ContactNumberArray",arrayContact);
```

Comment: change the return type of your AsyncTask (doInBackground) to ArrayList<NameContact>.

Comment: did you got the solution or not.?

Comment: no one more passed array list of values to request parameters

Comment: one more getting array values that's fine and one more one these array values passed to request parameters

Comment: i cant get you what you want actually.?

Comment: getting the array values of contacts that is fine

Comment: so whats the problem you facing?

Comment: array values are passed to request parameters RequestParams params = new RequestParams() ;

            for(int i=0;i < contacts.size();i++ )
            {
              params.put("ContactName",contacts[i].contactName);

             
            }

Comment: what is data type of contacts[i]

Comment: ArrayList<Contacts> contacts

Comment: does Contacts is the class i have suggested you to create.?

Comment: ya u suggested i will created

Comment: then you can get values from it like this - contacts[i].getName(); and contacts[i].getContact();   these are the getter methods inside that class.

Comment: params.put("ContactName", contacts.get(i).getName()); i write this is it possible

Comment: how can i post array of names and array of contact numbers to   client.post(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {}

Comment: you are going right to get values from ArrayList.. but to send Array data to client you must use JsonArray, and send it as a string.

Comment: ya but how to convert arraylist to jsonarray

Comment: how to convert arraylist to jsonarray briefly explain

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh. but am passing params to post method getting the josn response should be empty

Comment: am getting the response should be success and the contacts are set to array adapter shown in listview

Comment: so you got the solution now.??

Comment: ya solution am getting but  in success set the array list values to Array adapter

Comment: and one more response be success but in service the values are not showing what is the problem and how to identify the problem in coding or service problem

Comment: response should be success and in that how the contacts are set to array adapter in success

Comment: its a large process cannot explain in comments can you connect me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahesh-bhalerao-342811aa)

Comment: ya i will connect to u

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh u are sending the answer was correct

Answer (score 2):

create two lists

```
 ArrayList<String> contacts_name = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> contacts_number = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            PhoneNumber = c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contacts_name.add("ContactName:"+contactName);
            contacts_number.add("ContactNumber:"+PhoneNumber );

        }

        c.close();
```

Comment: which value i should return i want to return both values in doInBackground

Comment: what you trying to do pls explain

Comment: By above code getting the name and phone number in two arraylists but which arraylist i returned both arraylists are returned possible for asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You should go with pojo class or at the moment u can use this:

```
Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>> arr_list=new Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>>();

  arr_list.clear();

        Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
```

while (c.moveToNext()) {

```
        contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        PhoneNumber = c
                .getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

       HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
   map.put("name",""+contactName);
   map.put("number",""+PhoneNumber);    
   arr_list.add(map);   
    }

    c.close();
```

Log.d("array","arr="+arr_list);

you will have two keys and values with the position of array u can get the separate values.